# VB.NET WebRequest with API

Tags: vb.net

can someone tell me the best way to make a query in vb.net?
I want from the link: https://codefling.com/capi/category-2/?do=apicall
A specific file name (file_name) read out the file_version

Comment: That's a JSON object. You can use Json.Net (add the `Newtonsoft.Json` Package to your Project using the NuGet Package Manager of Visual Studio) or use the `System.Text.Json` (if you're targeting .Net Framework, it's available as a NuGet Package as well; directly available with .Net 5+)

Comment: Might also want to have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but how do I make the query? :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can make GET request to get the json from the url.

First you need to use:

```
Imports System.IO
```

Imports System.Net

In my case I create a button and call it btnGetJson

```
   Private Sub btnGetJson_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetJson.Click

    Dim url As String = "https://codefling.com/capi/category-2/?do=apicall"
    Dim webRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(webRequest, HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        tbResult.Text = reader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

End Sub
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: `Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url)`